# How to change/prepopulate SelectedIndex for each individual Combobox in DataGridTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I currently have a DataGrid that has 2 columns, one of which is a DataGridTextColumn that will display items in an ObservableCollection of strings, and the second one being a DataGridTemplateColumn that holds the DataGridCellTemplate which contains the DataTemplate that displays the Combobox. The combobox also binds to an ObservableCollection of strings. Everything binds and displays as it should.

**What I'm trying to achieve** is, due to a change in requirements and an addition of features, I need to change the index of the default entry being displayed in the Combobox (currently index 0). I have a new dictionary that contains entries from the first column as the key, and the value being a string that exists in the second column (combobox).

**i.e:** How do I change the selectedIndex of certain comboxes in the second column to 'pre-select' the index for known entries obtained from the dictionary?

**A Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example:**

What I currently have:

```
+--------------+-------------------+
| CustomerName |     Location      |
+--------------+-------------------+
| Bob          | <Select Location> |   <-- these are comboboxes
| John         | <Select Location> |
| Katy         | <Select Location> |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CustomerLocationGrid" Height="265" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-7,8,-2,-6" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerNameList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
 <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="customerDisplayList" Header="CustomerName" MinWidth="500" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayIndex="0"/>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="networkTypeTemplateColumn" Header="Location" MinWidth ="200" CanUserResize="True" Width="*">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <ComboBox x:Name="locationCombobox"  ItemsSource="{Binding locationList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="locationCombobox_SelectionChanged"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Where:

```
public ObservableCollection<String> CustomerNameList { get; set; }    //has a collection of Bob, John, Katy
public ObservableCollection<string> locationList { get; set;}   //has locations like Minnesota, Iowa, New York
```

(lists were populated from separate sources)

Note the DataTemplate-Combobox XAML above was what I learnt from [this tutorial on WPF comboboxes](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19493.wpf-best-combobox-tutorial-ever.aspx) (named "The Best WPF Combobox Tutorial Ever")

And how I have a third `Dictionary<string,string>` which from another source that has mappings of `Bob -> Minnesota`, `John -> Iowa`, but Katy is not there as it could not be predetermined and the user needs to select the location manually.

**I want to automatically select the index inside the combobox** so that the table looks like so, or make changes to Bob and Johns location:

```
+--------------+-------------------+
| CustomerName |     Location      |
+--------------+-------------------+
| Bob          | Minnesota         | <-- set as the displayedIndex
| John         | Iowa              |
| Katy         | <Select Location> |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

**What I've tried**:
My approach was to loop through each CustomerName entry, look it up in the dictionary, and if a value is returned from the dictionary, set the location. The strings are all identical so no matching is needed.

- Programatically loop through the DataGridTemplateColumn to get each combobox and set the selectedIndex, but failed to get the index of each customers combobox as well as the customername
- Attempt to utilitze the `Initialized` event handler (inspiration to do that was from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115256/why-is-this-wpf-combobox-not-showing-the-selected-value)) to use the objects (casted with `sender as ComboBox`, but could not get the index.

I have also attempted to use related solutions like [getting the index with VisualTreeHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875864/wpf-get-row-index-for-combobox-control-in-datagridtemplatecolumn) but felt it was too complicated (could not get the parent also) and a few other VisualTreeHelper method based solutions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be easy if you create a `Customer` ViewModel class with `Name` and `Location` property and create an `ObservableCollection<Customer> customers`and set that as the `ItemsSource` for the datagrid and use it to bind the columns.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Location {get; set;}
}

ObservableCollection<Customer> customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
```

Populate the `customers` collection with the names from `CustomerNamesList` and appropriate `locationList`

```
foreach(var customer in CustomerNameList )
{ 
    string location = string.Empty;
    //ThirdList is your Dictionary<string, string>
    if(ThirdList.Contains(customerName)) // Get customer location
        location = ThirdList[customerName];
    customers.Add(new Customer{Name=cusotmerName, Location=location});
}
```

In the XAML create a `CollectionViewSource` called `CustomerViewSource` and bind it to the datagrid's `ItemsSource`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomerViewSource"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In Code behind, set the `CustomerViewSource.Source` to the `ObservableCollection<Customer> customers`

```
CollectionViewSource CustomerViewSource = this.Resources["CustomerViewSource"] as CollectionViewSource;
CustomerViewSource.Source = customer;
```

In XAML, set the `DataGridTextColumn`'s Binding to `Name` property of the `customers` collection and set the `ComboBox.SelectedItem`'s Binding to `Location`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CustomerLocationGrid" Height="265" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-7,8,-2,-6" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomerViewSource}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" > 
 <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="customerDisplayList" Header="CustomerName" MinWidth="500" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="networkTypeTemplateColumn" Header="Location" MinWidth ="200" CanUserResize="True" Width="*">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <ComboBox x:Name="locationCombobox"  ItemsSource="{Binding locationList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Location}"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, your datagrid will show all the prepopulated customer info and for the ones without location info the user will be able to select it and you can retrieve it in the `customers` collection

Comment: thanks for answering, I've adapted the changes and it now uses the ViewModel as described, but my Comboboxes do are showing blank even if there exists a vlue in the Location property of the `Customer` Class

Comment: I've solved the issue, it turns out one of the strings that was saved in `Location` from the `ThirdList` did not match the string to be displayed in the combobox which binds to `locationList`. e.g `NewYork` vs `New York`. Thanks so much, you're an expert!

Comment: Also to tack on this answer for future reference, one might want to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` for `SelectedItem` binding in `Combobox` like so: `SelectedItem="{Binding Location, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` to ensure the property gets updated accordingly.